# Filtering an adjacency matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have got a `nx3` adjacency matrix that contains nodes in the first two dimension and the correspondant weight in the third dimension. I want to filter the matrix for specific thresholds (for nodes indexing). For example, I want to keep the adjacency matrix for nodes smaller than 10.000, 20.000, etc. Which is the most efficient way to do so in matlab? I tried to do the following, find the index which correspond to nodes:

```
counter = 1;
for i=1: size(graph4, 1)
   if (graph4(i,1) >30000) | (graph4(i,2) >30000)
      bucket(counter) = i;
      counter=counter+1;
   end
end
```

Comment: Is that a working code? Does it give your desired result? What is bucket? And what is the purpose of the counter?

Comment: Basically I want to store the indexes that after I ll remove from graph4 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the adjacency matrix is `A` as given below:

```
A =    
    8    1    6
    3    5    7
    4    9    2
   11    4    9
    6    8   10
    7   12    5
   17   10   15
   12   14   16
   13   18   11
```

If you want *both* column 1 and column 2 to be less than a value, you can do:

```
value = 10;
T = A(A(:,1) < value & A(:,2) < value, :)
T =    
    8    1    6
    3    5    7
    4    9    2
    6    8   10
```

The following line seems to give the same results as your sample code (but it doesn't seem like it fits your description.

```
value = 10000;
bucket = find((A(:,1)>value) | A(:,2)>value)
```

I guess you made a mistake and want to increment the counter above the bucket-line and initialize it as `counter = 0` before the loop? As it is now, it will be one more than the number of elements in the bucket-list.

Comment: Yes exactly i want both column to be lower than 7.